# scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline is giving ambiguous result

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have to find interploation between two sets of points `X,Y` such that:

```
X = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]  
Y = [0.947079910779078, 0.958840491330058, 0.948653507807658, .94687561871641, 0.94732364567882, 0.953963141055096, 0.943468711524127]
```

I tried finding the interpolation through `CubicSpline`

```
F_spline = scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline(X, Y, extrapolate='periodic'))
```

But if i cross-check, I get,

```
In [98]: F_spline_val = [F_spline(year) for year in X]
Out[98]: [array(0.94707991),
          array(0.95884049),
          array(0.94865351),
          array(0.94687562),
          array(0.94732365),
          array(0.95396314),
          array(0.94707991)]
```

Notice the last value here, calculated for `2017`, is `0.94707991`, whereas in the original variable, the value for `2017` was `0.943468711524127`. Which is clearly inaccurate. What am I missing here? Why there is an ambiguous value for `2017`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the keyword `extrapolate = periodic`. This assumes, as one might guess, that there is a periodicity in the dataset and [it has to fulfill the condition that `y[0] == y[-1]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline).

Since it is not clear, why your year-related data should be periodic and you violate the assumption, set `extrapolate = True` and you don't get strange results on the fringes of your dataset.